# Error:"Cannot use None as a query value" when trying to search with ListView

Tags: python-3.7, django-2.2

I have a search form including multiple fields for searching. I want to be able to search by entering value for any field and there should not be any force to enter values for all search fields:

My codes are as follow:

> ```
> models.py:
> ```

```
class Listings(models.Model):
relator = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
price = models.IntegerField()
bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
sqft = models.IntegerField()
lot_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_directory_path')
photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

> ```
> views.py:
> ```

```
class search(ListView):
template_name = 'listings/search.html'
queryset = Listings.objects.order_by('-list_date')
paginate_by = 6

# keywords
def get_queryset(self):
    description = self.request.GET.get('keywords')
    city = self.request.GET.get('city')
    state = self.request.GET.get('state')
    bedroom = self.request.GET.get('bedrooms')
    price = self.request.GET.get('price')
    object_list = self.queryset.filter(Q(description__icontains=description) |
                                       Q(city__iexact=city) |
                                       Q(state__iexact=state) |
                                       Q(bedrooms__lte=bedroom) |
                                       Q(price__lte=price))
    return object_list

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(search, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['state_choices'] = state_choices
    context['price_choices'] = price_choices
    context['bedroom_choices'] = bedroom_choices
    return context
```

> my template is:

```
          <form action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <!-- Form Row 1 -->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label class="sr-only">Keywords</label>
            <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword (Pool, Garage, etc)" value="{{ values.keywords }}">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label class="sr-only">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value="{{ values.city }}">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label class="sr-only">State</label>
            <select name="state" class="form-control">
              <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">State (All)</option>
              {% for key,value in state_choices.items %}
                  <option value="{{ key }}" 
                  {% if key == values.state %}
                    selected
                  {% endif %}
                  >{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Form Row 2 -->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label class="sr-only">Bedrooms</label>
            <select name="bedrooms" class="form-control">
              <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Bedrooms (Any)</option>
              {% for key,value in bedroom_choices.items %}
                  <option value="{{ key }}"
                  {% if key == values.bedrooms %}
                    selected
                  {% endif %}
                  >{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <select name="price" class="form-control">
              <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Max Price (All)</option>
              {% for key,value in price_choices.items %}
                  <option value="{{ key }}"
                  {% if key == values.price %}
                    selected
                  {% endif %}
                  >{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" type="submit">Submit form</button>
      </form>
```

> urls.py:

```
path('search', views.search, name='search')
```

## my error is:

> > ValueError at /listing/search
>
> Cannot use None as a query value
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing/search?keywords=&city=&price=500000
>   Django Version:   2.1.1 Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:
>
> Cannot use None as a query value
>
> Exception Location:
>     C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py
>   in build_lookup, line 1101 Python Executable:
>     C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\Scripts\python.exe Python Version:
>     3.7.3 Python Path:
>
> ['C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping', 
>   'C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\Scripts\python37.zip', 
>   'C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\lib', 
>   'C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\Scripts', 
>   'c:\users\lela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib', 
>   'c:\users\lela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env', 
>   'C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\shopping\env\lib\site-packages']
>
> Server time:  Sat, 14 Sep 2019 20:25:53 +0000

Answer (score 0):

I need more code bu from what i see, I suppose that problem lies here:

```
.get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

as you don't provide function with this argument, it tries to query None and then is raising exception, try put there static data like '42069' or something idk and see if it changes anything

Comment: as you wrote, my error is in get_context_data(**kwargs) which returns None. I don't know how to fix it